# How to block browser from using?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, brave

I have some exams coming ahead, but I have an addiction to YouTube. Due to this I have Customized many things in my settings like I have installed extensions like StayFocusd and StayFree which are used for blocking sites, in regedit I have disabled accessing new tabs and private ones but I cannot access regedit again, I have removed MS Edge, disabled MS Store, and also restricted the use of getting multiple tabs to open and also blocked the browser to access from securities.

After blocking, I have downloaded sites as a shortcut app which I use for my Studies. This means I used the websites as app but not the browser. Few days ago I got a small loop in the site app, that it have the puzzle shape showing extensions running in browser and shortcut app and it takes about 5 seconds to turn on the extensions after app is opened, which is enough for me to go to settings and turn of the extensions (and an advantage is that it takes me to browser settings even if it blocks me from security which makes it easier to go to homepage of browser).

This made me easier to get my craving back .Now I want to block using my browser or just make it more tougher to access, or I just want that extension icon to vanish off so that I could only use my study related websites apps only. By the way I use Brave as my browser.

Please do not downvote as it is a serious problem for me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In the title should "using" be "youtube"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To block YouTube in the Brave browser :

- Position to `brave://settings/shields/filters`
- Go down to the "Create custom filters" section
- Add `youtube.com` to the text box
- Click the "Save changes" button.

Comment: Please could you specify where I can get Manage Blocked Sites as in "security" there is no such thing

Comment: Sorry, this was for an old version of Brave. I updated my answer for the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to block youtube at the router stage. Most routers these days have the ability to add a URL blocklist, so use this but get a friend to set the admin password to prevent you from turning it off.

Comment: But it will also block for my family. So is there any other alternative.

Comment: Infact, when I was trying it use, a pop up displayed saying that https are not used for URL filter

Comment: what router is it? I may be able to help. The router needs to set an IP address just for you, and then to only block one site to you, not everybody else. Some routers can do this - It's like a kids mode.